# Euler's identity is 0 (Python)?

Tags: education

Today I'm trying to prove the Euler's identity which is $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ by Python.
My code is as follows:

```
euler = math.e
pi = np.pi

cos_pi = np.cos(pi)
sin_pi = np.sin(pi)
euler_id = euler**(imaginary*pi)

print((cos_pi+imaginary*sin_pi)+1)
print('e^(i*pi): %s' %eulers_id) # output = (-1+1.2246467991473532e-16j) 
print('e^(i*pi)+1 =: %s' %(eulers_id+1)) # output = 1.2246467991473532e-16j
```

What I get is an imaginary number, did I do something wrong here?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The `1.2246467991473532e-16` makes the result a **very small** imaginary that "should be" zero. You're simply encountering an implementation issue with inexact floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: "Real" numbers such as $\pi$ and $e$ are idealized mathematical objects usually requiring infinite decimal expansions. Because we don't have the time to write infinite decimal expansions, when "real" number arithemetic is implemented in ***real*** life, there are usually roundoff errors.

Comment: This is the double-precision [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). A double-precision calculation, such as the one python is using here, cannot be more accurate than that epsilon. Thus, the result is consistent with zero.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your answer. I solved this issue by using np.isclose((eulers_id+1), 0)

Comment: In python, imaginary numbers can be written as $a*1j$.

Comment: On the off chance it wasn't obvious, the final result is presented as $1.2246467991473532 \times 10^{-16} j$, *not* $1.2246467991473532e - 16j$, with $e$ being Euler's constant. :-)

Comment: You might keep in mind: if you are truly interested in a rigorous proof of Euler's identity, a Python calculation, even one using np.isclose((eulers_id+1), 0), is not going to be sufficient. At best you're gathering calculational evidence, but you're certainly not getting a proof.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, yes, you're right. I use Python is only for a programming demonstration. :)